# Magnify django thumbnail on mouse hover in django admin

Tags: css, django, image, admin, thumbnails

How to add css hover effect to this django admin function that displays thumbnail in the admin section. To magnify the size of the image

```
def image_tag(self):
        if self.image:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width: 50px; height:40px;" />' % self.image.url)
        else:
            return 'No Image Found'
    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static directory inside of your django 
app->static->app_name->css->style.css

Then in your `admin.py` you add the style like this

```
class Media:   
    css = {
     'all': ('app_name/css/style.css',)
    }
```

inside the model admin.
example:

```
class ModelNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      class Media:   
             css = {
             'all': ('app_name/css/style.css',)
            }
```

then write your custom css

Answer (score 2):

I recommend wrapping the image on a  or another element, and on hover set the position of the image to absolute, that  way if won't mess up the layout when you magnify it.

Check out this codepen example and let me know if this works for you:
https://codepen.io/darthrubens/pen/Zqgwoa

```css
.profile-pic-wrapper {
  width: 60px;
  height: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.profile-pic-wrapper img {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
}

.profile-pic-wrapper:hover img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-pic-wrapper">
  <img src="https://media.bizj.us/view/img/10179818/nicolascage2011cc*750xx617-823-17-0.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
  Some other content
</div>
```

Comment: I was looking for way to attach the style to django admin